# Difficulty understanding how pandas.read_csv() parses "doublequoted" text in a quoted field containing the delimiter when parameter doublequote=False

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I was digging into a few of the `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()` and `pandas.read_csv()` parameters around handling quote characters when dealing with text that contains the delimiter in it and ran into some confusion about the `doublequote` parameter. According to the docs, `doublequote` is used to "indicate whether or not to interpret two consecutive quotechar elements INSIDE a field as a single quotechar element."

However, if I use `doublequote=False` when reading in a file that was created using the default `to_csv()` settings (which defaults `doublequote` to `True`, I get a result that goes against my expectations. And while this scenario is a bit far-fetched, I'd like to understand what is happening.

Say that I have the following:

```
text = 'simple,"simple"'
df = pd.DataFrame([{'col': text}])
```

and therefore `df` gives

```
                col
0   simple,"simple"
```

If I use `to_csv()` to write this out to a csv file and then inspect the file

```
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)

with open('test.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line, end='')
```

I get

```
col
"simple,""simple"""
```

Now, if I read this file in using `pd.read_csv('test.csv')` with the default value for `doublequote` of `True`, I get as output

```
                col
0   simple,"simple"
```

which is what I would expect. But if I do this using `pd.read_csv('test.csv', doublequote=False, quotechar='"')`, I get

```
                  col
0   simple,"simple"""
```

But shouldn't I expect to instead see

```
                  col
0   simple,""simple""
```

instead as the output?

**Edit:**

The text `"simple,""simple"""` is interpreted by python as one string given by the concatenation of 3 string literals `"simple,"`, `"simple"`, and the empty string `""`. But how is the text parsed by the csv reader? We see that `simple,"simple"""` is what gets read in. Here is my partial guess:

1. the first `"` is recognized as a quotechar (by default) designating that the reader should read in any delimiters encountered as part of the field until it finds the next unescaped quotechar. The quotechar itself is not read in.
2. Then `simple,` is processed until the quotechar after the comma is encountered

But I don't know what happens next. Does the quotechar after the comma get read in or ignored as is the case with the initial quotechar? We see that one quote after the comma is read in --- but which one? Does one of these quotechars flip the "read-delimiter-as-part-of-field' flag? Or can only a quotechar encountered before a delimiter or newline flip this flag? Why are there three quotes read in at the end of the line?

Comment: You can see in the read_csv parameter decription,
```doublequote : bool, default True
        Control quoting of `quotechar` inside a field.
``` So based on ```doublequote``` value it checks ```quotechar```. If ```doublequote``` set to False, unable to to apply ```quotechar```

Comment: @Mazhar I believe that `quotechar` gets a default value of `"`. I've added some more content to my post which hopefully helps clarify my confusion a bit more.

Comment: Looks like if ```doublequote``` set to False, it consider ```quotechar``` apply only once.And then keep it same as it is.   Removing first ```"``` and then remove the 2nd encountered ```"```

Comment: You have to take into account the `quoting` parameter.